# Select by attributes on PYQGIS 2.14 Essen

Tags: qgis, python, select-by-attribute

I'm trying to make a selection by attribute with python on QGIS Essen, but it looks like I am making a mistake on the script and I can not find it. Can somebody tell me what I have made wrong, or how can I select attributes without using the select by attribute algorithm?

This is my script:

```
pas14=processing.runalg('qgis:selectbyattribute',r'C:\Users\s.galan\Desktop\TFM_SORAYA\03_Model\Capes_script\polygonize1.shp','valor',0,3,r'C:\Users\s.galan\Desktop\TFM_SORAYA\03_Model\Capes_script\select1')
select1=QgsVectorLayer(r'C:\Users\s.galan\Desktop\TFM_SORAYA\03_Model\Capes_script\select1.shp','select1','ogr')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(select1)
```

And this is the error:

```
Error: Wrong number of parameters

ALGORITHM: Select by attribute

    INPUT <ParameterVector>
    FIELD <parameters from INPUT>
    OPERATOR <ParameterSelection>
    VALUE <ParameterString>
    OUTPUT <OutputVector>

OPERATOR(Operator)

    0 - =
    1 - !=
    2 - >
    3 - >=
    4 - <
    5 - <=
    6 - begins with 
    7 - contains
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the confusion lies with the `OUTPUT` parameter where the algorithm **does not require this** as you're only selecting attributes from the **same layer**. Remove this from your algorithm (this should also be removed from the documentation in my opinion).

So your algorithm should look like:

```
pas14=processing.runalg('qgis:selectbyattribute',r'C:\Users\s.galan\Desktop\TFM_SORAYA\03_Model\Capes_script\polygonize1.shp','valor',0,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually ignore this -  I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: What was the bug you mentioned? Was it related to `"Unsupported field type "Integer64"`?